# Database name as variable in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I am creating a MySQL dump file, that needs to run with multiple databases.
The structure is almost like this :

```
SET @parent_database = 'db_name';
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW t_colours AS
   SELECT `key_name`, `value`
   FROM @parent_database. `colours` as COLOURS WHERE 1;
```

When I run this query next time, my plan is to only change the variable `parent_database`.

Is this possible?

Everytime now I run this, I receive an error :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@parent_database.`colours` as COLOURS WHERE 1' at line 1

Any way to make this happen?

There are many more views to create.

Comment: you can't use var for tables or columns name

Comment: You can't get data from the database without making connection to the respected database so it won't work;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute the queries the mysql thinks of table names as objects and not as string, and hence this would not work as you would expect.

However, there is a way  out and you could use something similar to below snippet.

```
SET @parent_database = 'db_name';
SET @q = CONCAT('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW t_colours AS SELECT `key_name`,`value` FROM', @parent_database, '.`colours` as COLOURS WHERE 1;');
PREPARE stmt FROM @q; 
EXECUTE stmt; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```